# SSH sudo inside script different behaviour

Tags: shell, ssh, sudo

I'm trying to set some automation inside local network and started working with some shell scripting and something that I saw - very strange behaviour SSH inside script according to how script running(with or without sudo):

What I have:
ComputerA and ComputerB.

### Inside `ComputerA`:

A shell script `script.sh`:

```
cp /dir1/file1 /dir2/file2
ssh username@ComputerB "sudo reboot"
```

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file with some configurations to work without ssh-keys (they always changes on ComputerB):

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

### Inside `ComputerB`:

In `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

When I connecting through SSH to ComputerA and running **script.sh** without sudo, I get permission error to write to /dir2 (it's OK) and next command on ComputerB executes normally (reboots ComputerB), but I'm running **sudo script.sh**. It copy file and then I got strange - SSH asks me username password. Tried different variants to change ssh command to something like:

```
ssh -t username@ComputerB "echo user_pass | sudo -S reboot"
```

but nothing helped.
So I need help to figure out what happens and what to do to execute `sudo script.sh` without entering password for ssh command inside.
Thanks!

Comment: You may need to edit the file permissions. Can you go to the directory with script.sh and run ```ls -l``` and let me know the results?

Comment: @mjlitz script.sh have '777' permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run `script.sh` with `sudo` on computerA; instead modify the script like so:

```
sudo cp /dir1/file1 /dir2/file2
ssh username@ComputerB "sudo reboot"
```

The reason that you're seeing the **strange behaviour** is that you're actually becoming root on *computerA* (I assume you have a keypair set-up for your regular user and expect to connect to *computerB* passwordless?), and that **root** on *computerA* doesn't have a keypair that *computerB* knows about.

Comment: Yes, that make sense and `sudo cp` will do the work, and for some reason I don't want make `sudo cp`. I don't get why in this two situations I'm connecting through SSH using same `username` so I expect there is no difference how I run script.sh - with or without sudo.

Comment: @Doe - Yes, there is.  with sudo it tries to use `root`'s key-pair from *computerA*, without it yours.  The **username** is only relevant for the remote end and has no impact on the selection of the keys.  If you don't want to use `sudo` inside the script make sure that your normal account has read-/write-access to both `dir1` **and** `dir2`.